# Code coverage for Selenium runs like we do with Emma and Cobertura for Unit tests?

Tags: selenium, java-8, code-coverage, cobertura, emma

Is there any way we can do code coverage for Selenium runs like we do with Emma and Cobertura for Unit tests?

Tried below Links but they do not support Java 8. I have a web application (war) built on Java 8 and deployed on tomcat 7. I want to do a code coverage of Java classes and JSP on the instrument war.
[Link 1](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-we-can-do-code-coverage-for-Selenium-runs-like-we-do-with-Emma-and-Cobertura-for-Unit-tests)
[Link 2](http://emma.sourceforge.net/samples.html)
[Link 3](https://code.google.com/p/cobertura-coverage-for-war/wiki/InstallationAndUsage)

Both Emma and Cobertura does not support Java 8. The above links are good for Java 7 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/). It fully supports Java-8 and integrates well with IDEs, build systems and continuous integration systems.

Comment: Found very good [Link](http://car-online.fr/en/blog/fabien_duchene/2013-05-03-Java%20Code%20Coverage%20in%20Tomcat%20JSP%20applications,%20e.g.,%20WebGoat%20with%20Jacoco/)